# Delphi 10.3 RAD Server: Unable to access resource endpoints hosted on Windows Server 2016 IIS (ISAPI dll) from browser

Tags: iis, windows-server-2016, delphi-10.3-rio

Unable to access resource endpoints hosted on Windows Server 2016 IIS (ISAPI dll) from browser.

"error":"Resource not found: /companies","description":"The request does not identify a known application, resource, endpoint, or entity"

Resource end points are successful access from Windows 10 IIS.

Why are they are loaded in non-development Windows Server 2016 IIS?

Comment: You obviously are struggling with Delphi access endpoints, but it isn't very clear from your post what exactly the problem is. Please rephrase, spend some time and text to clearly explain the problem in steps, and illustrate with reproducible minimal code snippets and debug output if that is available.

Comment: Can you describe your perblem in detail? how did you access the resource end points? and where do you want to load it?

Answer (score 0):

Resolved.  The issue was with a custom component on resource Datamodule forms:  A variable was declared as a LongInt when it should been a NativeInt thereby causing an "Out of Memory" error at runtime when compiled 64 bit.  It appears during Initialization the exception prevented the load of the resource bpl and therefore IIS could not redirect to the resource endpoints.